# PHP , SQL Resource id #10 . How can i get the value?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to get the value from this query and insted i get Resource id #10

```
echo$result = mysql_query("SELECT car.currentkm FROM car INNER JOIN details ON car.id= ".$_REQUEST['cartype']." AND details.cartype = ".$_REQUEST['cartype']."");
if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    $old = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
   echo$old['oldkm'];
}
else {
    echo 1;
}
```

Comment: I can't get your code to make sense, why are you echoing your $result = mysql_query? andyou are only fetching currentKm, but you are trying to display oldkm? secondly mysql is outdated and security flawed, you should use PDO or mysqli instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using `echo` before `$result=`??? this is what is showing `ResourceId`.

try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT car.currentkm FROM car INNER JOIN details ON car.id= ".$_REQUEST['cartype']." AND details.cartype = ".$_REQUEST['cartype']."");
if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    $old = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo $old['currentkm'];
}
else {
    echo 1;
}
```

**N.B.:**

1- using `$_REQUEST` directly inside queries like you're doing makes your code WIDE open for sql injection. You need to clean your variables before using them inside queries.

2- mysql_* functions are deprecated and will be removed in later php versions, you should start using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli), additionally using prepared statements in one of these drivers will protect your code against sql injection without you having to clean the variables.